# Send multiple http requests to a web service

Tags: c#

I want to send multiple HTTP requests to a web service using C# client,  just to stress the web service. I tried sending the requests using Async calls and calling that method from multiple threads. But after certain amount of threads, increasing threads is yielding in decreased requests/min.

Note: I am trying to submit the HTTP requests with 128 KB data.

Can anyone help me on which should be the best approach to achieve what I wanted.?

Comment: Have you tried using multiple proxy objects? Or how do you communicate with the webservice?

Comment: I am directly sending the requests to http service using its URI. Its a restful webservice

Answer (score 1):

Can you look here:

[Multiple HTTP request in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972988/multiple-http-request-in-c-sharp)

http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/httpgetrequestdotnetworkprogramming10i.html

and also can you write more about your problem?